# Why was my "identify this game" question removed?

Tags: support, game-identification

> UPDATE:  As of [16/3/2012](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-identification), Identify this game questions are now prohibited on the site.

I had forgotten the name of the game, again, and decided to look at my old question about it.  To my surprise, I discovered that [it's been deleted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8533/help-identifying-old-mac-game-with-sharks-puzzles)!

The original question/answer can be found [here](http://gamingqna.blogspot.com/2011/09/help-identifying-old-mac-game-with.html).  As far as I can tell, it's specific, descriptive, and has a correct answer chosen.  So why was it deleted?

Comment: It was Jeff. I think you'd need to ask him.

Comment: @Raven: Er, isn't that what I'm doing?  I can't just call up his cell-phone to ask...

Comment: I apologize; my point was, I agree - I can't see any reason for the question to be removed. It was answered and had no recent activity at the time of deletion. If there was some logical reason for its deletion, I can't see it.

Comment: @Raven: It has been over a week - would you be able to contact Jeff for me, or un-delete this question yourself?

Answer (score 4):

I was generally removing any older [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) question with a score of -1 or lower, but if you want this particular one back, I have no objection to that.

Longer term, this tag needs to die, with extreme prejudice..

Comment: Why must you destroy everything that is good.  =[

Comment: @GnomeSlice Except ITG isn't good.

Comment: @gnome I think these are kind of harmful "fun" in the medium to long term. I need to blog about this..

Comment: @JeffAtwood That sounds like an excellent idea, considering how divided the community seems (to me) to be on the issue.

Comment: blogged by @JeffAtwood: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/