# What should be done with questions asking for game identification?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, game-identification

> ***UPDATE**: Identify this game (ITG) questions based on the asker's memory are now off topic on the site.*
>
> The community reached this decision with 34 vs 27 votes
>
> New ITG questions will be closed immediately, and we will start applying this policy retroactively in time.

---

Following a series of discussions carried out here on meta, we have attempted to address the current situation of "Identify This Game" questions on Gaming.  The situation is complex, and both sides have put forth arguments as to why they should be permitted or prohibited.

The time has come to make a decision.  We've narrowed the field to two choices:

1. Identify this game questions should be prohibited.
2. Identify this game questions should be allowed, under the guidelines given [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4124/call-for-concepts-determining-new-identify-this-game-criteria)

If you need to review the previous debates on the subject, (and I **highly** suggest that you do) each answer has a rundown of the relevant meta posts.  You may also wish to review the thread that started this debate:

[What is the point of "help me remember this game" questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/what-is-the-point-of-help-me-remember-this-game-questions)

A few ground rules:

- Voting will end **one week** after this question is posted, on the 16th of March, at around 18:00 UTC.
- **Downvotes will be ignored** to standardize the voting process.  **Express your opinion with upvotes.**
- Be civil - no attacking people who don't agree with you.

Comment: Is there any chance of option 2 with a provision to review the landscape after implementation. Believe it or not, I *want* to give supporters of ITG one last chance to prove to me that real guidelines can work, but I'm worried about the finality implied by this process.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, if you think it'd be worthwhile to test drive, we can implement the guidelines this week and test them while the voting is open.  How's that strike you and/or everyone?

Comment: I'd prefer implement them now, and **postpone** the voting until it's been done for a week or so personally.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I don't think having this "test period" is a good idea, mostly because I want a final decision as soon as possible, though I appreciate your motivation on this. If you are uncertain that the proposed criteria for allowing them will work as planned, I say you should vote against keeping ITGs.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, there's nothing that says we *can't* revisit this decision later after time has passed.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, to elaborate, if you think the new criteria should get a fair shake, then vote for that option.  If things are *still* really bad, we can reevaluate the decision to allow them 6 months or a year down the road.

Comment: If we go forward with the criteria, we should jump in with both feet - which is going to be "capital W" Work.  If the overall consensus is that ITG is terrible no matter what we do, let's get that out of the way before we start this effort.

Comment: Agreed, this would be too much work to just "test out" right now. If it totally doesn't work at all we can always revise policy and delete everything later (which is much easier). If the majority opinion is "delete 'em" we should know that now

Comment: I think testing it out is a good idea, but the site is swimming in ME3 questions so I don't think this is the best TIME for it.

Comment: @Shinrai, my first attempt was unsuccessful: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55497/a-gameboy-game-from-my-childhood#comment80107_55497

Comment: I'm just coming into the debate now, but where else on the internet *could* you go to to get a game identified?  I've tracked down something I was entirely unable to identify on my own after several years of on-and-off trying.

Comment: @Bobson, this is actually a pretty common forum game - [XKCD](http://fora.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=18807) and [SomethingAwful](http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=2925708) both have forum threads dedicated to this topic.  I will also point out that SE is not the "catch-all" of things that other places on the internet do not do.  Even if there was nowhere else to do this sort of thing, that would not imply that it is on-topic here.

Comment: @lunboks A post needs at least a score of +3 to retain the reputation after deletion, in addition to 60 days of life. In that scenario, there will always be a positive reputation change, with or without the off-topic downvote, if there is any retention.

Answer (score 24):

## Identify this game questions should be prohibited on this site.

### Arguments for this position:

- [Let's Talk About UFO's, and I don't mean the Ask Question Mothership](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3998/1719)

  - [Origami's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4002/2259)
- [Let's Play The Guessing Game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)
- Do we still like 'Identify This Game' questions?

  - [tzenes's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2680/1719)
  - [data compiled by agent86 about their usefulness to the site](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4106/14)
  - [StrixVaria's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4118/1719)
- [What is the point of “help me remember this game” questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1455/1719)

  - [more data compiled by tzenes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2478/2259)
- [What level of exclusion is healthy for the site at this point?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/818/what-level-of-exclusion-is-healthy-for-the-site-at-this-point) (written regarding game-rec, but can be repurposed)

Comment: I'm Commander Shepard and this is my favorite answer on the Citadel.

Comment: Notice how non-controversial this option is in the comments? Hm. Weird.

Comment: "Point blank deletion" doesn't exactly have many nuances to discuss.  The votes are the valuable signal here, not the comments.

Comment: @MatthewRead It is often the case that the simplest course of action is the best course of action. I'm just pointing out that this is the simple solution, and the other one is full of controversy still. That is all.

Comment: The simplest course of action is to do nothing ;)

Comment: @MatthewRead It's not, actually. You're never in the chat, but doing nothing leads to way more headaches than banning them :P Not to mention that that's not one of the options anyway.

Comment: @StrixVaria I'm not *proposing* we do nothing, lol.  I maintain that doing nothing is simplest -- the headaches only come from doing something, like trying to clean up the mess resulting from the current state of things :P

Comment: @MatthewRead - If doing nothing was the simplest, there wouldn't be so many meta questions on this topic.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I don't see how doing something (discussing on meta) indicates anything about how complicated doing nothing would be.  In any case, this is getting pretty tangential -- count me out of further discussion along this line :P

Answer (score 21):

## Identify this game questions should be allowed on this site, but must adhere to [this criteria](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4124/call-for-concepts-determining-new-identify-this-game-criteria) to avoid closure and deletion.

### Arguments for this position:

- Do we still like 'Identify This Game' questions?

  - [Oak's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2681/2259)
  - [Matthew Read's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/2259)
  - [Joel's response to the blog post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4101/2259) (originally on one of the aforementioned deleted posts)
- What is the point of “help me remember this game” questions?

  - [badp's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1456/2259)
  - [Oak's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1462/2259)
  - [John Rudy's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1467/2259)

Comment: If we go this route is there a plan in place to handle the existing catalog of ITG questions in any way? (Perhaps we can steal SO's shiny new 'historic significance' lock?)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, the plan thus far is to enforce this criteria retroactively.  (Grace feels strongly about this)

Comment: I concur that it should be retroactively. We could wait some time before starting to enforce it as to give OPs time to format their questions appropriately though

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz we should apply it retroactively by closing ITGs, but I personally think we should not delete them if they have a useful answer, instead using that "historic significance" thing you mention. It's just because I despise deleting posts with useful information. But I'm guessing a lot of users will claim this is still a broken window of a sort, and they do have a point.

Comment: I support retroactive enforcement of ITGs without an accepted answer.  Give ITGs with an accepted answer a few months to self edit before votes to close are cast.

Comment: @MBraedley So just because their less-than-adequate description still got a correct answer, they don't deserve to be closed? No. If need to be consistent with enforcement. No exceptions.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Well then at least save them for last.  I realize that may only give them an extra day, but why close questions that can easily be saved?

Comment: Why not discuss how to deploy this solution or the other solution after the vote is finalized?

Comment: @Stephen  Because how it will be deployed could affect whether or not we vote for it.

Comment: @Sterno We could also argue about whether prohibiting future ITGs means deleting the existing ones.  It really only muddies the waters on a fairly straightforward proposal.

Comment: @Stephen They'd be destroyed, same as Game-Rec was.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Sure, but we **could** argue about it, just to muddy the waters pointlessly.  The prevailing opinion was that these changes would be retroactively applied.  If that's not clear then it was too early to start voting.

Comment: @RavenDreamer If the questions are closed, and not outright destroyed, then if someone is interested in trying to flesh out the question to fit the format, they can try to reopen it after the fact.  Simple.

Comment: @Stephen Who are these people who are going to theoretically update the old ITGs that have answers, and what value does it provide? The one person who was ever going to be helped by the vague question that happened to get an answer has already been helped. It seems silly to retroactively "clean up" the question so that it matches the answer and fits our new criteria. I mean, at that point, let's just copy & paste the wikipedia article for the page in there and get a real complete description for the next person who goes searching for it.

Comment: Enforcing retroactively doesn't mean we're going to close and delete on Friday afternoon.  There are, at present, almost 600 ITG questions on the site.  If, say, 30 people were to divide the work, that'd be 20 questions to improve each.  Likely we'd find a good portion of them are actually delete worthy, so that's a high number per person.  I've no problem with doing 20 questions worth of improvement, and I'd probably easily do 40.  If everyone interested in keeping them chips in, we could do this in 1-2 weeks, tops.