# What's happen to my reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

First, I admit that I care about my reputation points.

This morning (eastern time), I had 1414 points. Tonight, I have 1379 points. What happened? Did the reputation get corrected like stackoverflow 3-4 weeks ago? On stackoverflow, there had a link explaining what happened, is there a similar link here?

Comment: The thing 3-4 weeks ago (constant rep recalcs) was across all SE sites.  Have you ever asked any identify-this-game questions?  They were all recently deleted, and your rep along with them.

Comment: There was a link explaining what happened. You probably missed it. The recalc, like every other change on the network, gets pushed out on SE 2.0 sites like Gaming before it happened on SO. Anyway, if you want to, read about it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely lost points because it was recently decided that ["identify this game" questions are no longer on topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4168/15643) and as such those questions were closed and removed from the system. This likely resulted in a loss in your reputation if you have ever answered those types of questions. If you'd like to find out more specifically what questions you lost it on, you can go to your user page, click on the reputation (or simply click on your reputation in the bar) and check the box at the bottom of the page that says "Show removed posts" and that will show you where you lost your rep.

Comment: I just checked. He'd have lost a grand total of... 20 from ITG questions.

Comment: specifically: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/14499/2259

Comment: Unaccept for the other 15 maybe? Or was it maybe an accepted answer also?

Comment: @NickT Can't see. Not 10k.

Comment: 10ks can't see accepts on deleted questions, but that's a perfect numerical fit so: probably.