# Consistency with the ID Request Ruling

Tags: discussion, game-identification

I was reading [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-identification) that ID Requests are Off Topic on Arqade, and in the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) it says as much, however i asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129218/what-game-does-extra-credits-use-in-the-working-conditions-episode-at-612) long after that ruling and there are still questions which are ID Requests which don't get closed, the recent one (as of posting this) is [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173170/what-game-is-featured-in-amazon-new-phone-page) on the 19 of June 2014.

So i am wondering, is ID Requests off topic or not?

Answer (score 6):

They are off topic UNLESS, as stated in the close reason for those types of questions (and likely other places), they feature some sort of artifact we can use to identify them by. As you can see, both questions have a picture to help us narrow down what game it is, and thus, they are on topic.

Comment: Would it not be better to say that ID Request will be closed for being too broad or unclear unless they follow a strick guidelines like what [anime and manga has](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/892/63) rather than saying they are off-topic, or even at least separating the line in the tour about ID requests and recommendations to only have recommendations then bellow it indicate that id requests must have an artifact?

Comment: Our guidelines are that they need an artifact, and otherwise we deem them off-topic. I can look into possibly changing the help center text to include that requirement, but other than that, I feel that nothing else needs to be done.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Thanks, the Tour saying ID questions are off-topic made me think they're no longer welcome here.

Comment: For the most part they aren't but you're right, perhaps we need to be clearer there is an exception to the rule :)